# Is /etc/sysconfig/static-routes a deprecated method for adding persistent routes?

Tags: networking, rhel, route

RHEL 5.x

I'm comfortable with adding static routes via `/etc/sysconfig/static-routes`.  When I was reviewing [Red Hat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-static-routes.html) though, I didn't see this mentioned.  Instead, the recommendation was to use `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-<interface>`

Is the `static-routes` file a deprecated method for adding persistent routes?

Answer (score 4):

If you bring an interface down, any routes that used that interface will be deleted. This happens automatically in the kernel.

If you then bring the interface up again, `/etc/sysconfig/static-routes` won't be run again, so the routes specified in that file for this interface are lost. However, if you put the routes in the interface-specific file, then they *will* be restored by the system when you bring the interface up again.

Hence it's better to put the routes in the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-<interface>` file.

Answer (score 1):

That file looks like it contains non-interface-specific static routes, via some grepping around under `/etc`:

```
# grep -rl static-route .
./rc.d/init.d/network
./ppp/ipv6-up
./ppp/ip-up.ipv6to4
./sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-sit
./sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-ipv6
# perl -00 -ne 'print if m/static-routes/' rc.d/init.d/network 
        # Add non interface-specific static-routes.
        if [ -f /etc/sysconfig/static-routes ]; then
           grep "^any" /etc/sysconfig/static-routes | while read ignore args ; do
              /sbin/route add -$args
           done
        fi    
        # Add non interface-specific static arp entries.
        if [ -f /etc/ethers ]; then
                /sbin/arp -f /etc/ethers
        fi
```

These files exist on RHEL5, 6, and 7, though may not be run if the `network` service is disabled, as I have no idea whether `NetworkManager` references the `static-routes` file; that would require actually enabling it and probably running it under `strace -o blah -ff -e trace=file ...` to see what it touches.